# All drivers stopped working?

Tags: wireless, kernel, gpu-driver

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 about 2 weeks ago, and after i installed my proprietary graphics drivers it was working fine. When i turned it on today, the graphics driver wasnt working, forcing me into 4k display and not turning on after i close the screen, but the driver is listed as still being used. To add insult to injury, it also no longer recognizes any internet connection, wired or wireless. Is there a known solution to this problem?

**EDIT:** results for `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

```
ii linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic 4.4.0-31.50 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic 4.4.0-38.57 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic 4.4.0-42.62 amd64 Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic 4.4.0-31.50 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic 4.4.0-38.57 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iHR linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic 4.4.0-42.62 amd64 (no description available)
ii linux-image-generic 4.4.0.38.40 amd64 Generic Linux kernel image
```

**EDIT 2:**

Inspiron 7559
Intel i7-6700HQ
GTX 960M
500GB Crucial_CT500MX2 (install location)
1TB Toshiba MQ02ABD1

Not sure what other hardware is important here

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

Comment: Please also add to your question your hardware configuration, for example through the command `sudo lshw -short`

Comment: For some reason linux-image-extra is only half installed for the latest kernel and that package has the wireless drivers

Comment: How do i the half installed package?

Comment: In terminal, type `dkms status`. If you get a list of drivers, then you need to make sure that **secure boot** is turned off in your BIOS. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

Comment above worked, copied for visibility:

In terminal, type `dkms status`. If you get a list of drivers, then you need to make sure that secure boot is turned off in your BIOS. Thanks to @heynnema for the idea.

Cheers, Al